# When does a distributed system need ZooKeeper

Tags: solr, cassandra, apache-zookeeper

Why do some distributed systems like Solr or Kafka need ZooKeeper, but some distributed systems like Cassandra don't?

Answer (score 8):

ZooKeeper provides a strongly consistent store for critical system state. Many systems, e.g. Storm and Kafka rely on ZooKeeper to do service discovery and leader election. Because ZooKeeper's ZAB protocol falls on the CP side of the CAP theorem, it can guarantee that two clients will not see different views of the same system. So, for instance, Kafka will not mistakenly believe both node A and node C are the leader for the same partition.

These systems simply use ZooKeeper because it's a very well tested and proven technology for storing this type of critical metadata. ZooKeeper acts as a central point for coordination. Cassandra, however, has a more decentralized architecture and implements its own consensus algorithm (Paxos) rather than relying on an external CP store like ZooKeeper. Depending on how Cassandra uses its gossip and consensus protocols, it may simply make some concessions that systems like Kafka and Solr do not. This allows Cassandra to be devoid of dependencies on external systems like ZooKeeper which can generally tolerate less failures than can HA systems.

Comment: How does dynamic reconfiguration in zookeeper could better it's support to the distributed systems? Can Kafka and Solr benefit from this feature of zookeeper added from 3.5.x in zookeeper?

Answer (score 1):

Systems that need Zookeeper relies on it for cluster coordination. Cassandra architecture is different because it's a peer-to-peer system. As consequence of that the coordination is "distribuited" among each node.

Answer (score 0):

*** See 2024 Update below***

### Original Answer::

**In Kafka Consumers of topics register themselves in ZooKeeper**, in order to coordinate with each other and balance the consumption of data.
Consumers can also store their offsets in ZooKeeper by setting offsets.storage=zookeeper.

**Solr embeds and uses Zookeeper as a repository for cluster configuration and coordination -** think of it as a distributed filesystem that contains information about all of the Solr servers.

Apart from these [zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/) is used in many other systems like Hadoop Highavailabilty, HBase.

### 2024 Update::

Kafka, as early as Aug 2022 has been working on [removing ZooKeeper](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-833%3A+Mark+KRaft+as+Production+Ready) and replacing with KRaft, and KRaft will be the only option by about Apr '24